# zend community server very slow on first request with OS X 10.6

Tags: apache, apache2, osx-snow-leopard, zend-server-ce

I have installed Zend CE 4.0.5 for php 5.3 on my Mac Book Pro running Snow Leopard osx 10.6.

I use this setup for my local development environment.

When I haven't done a request in a while ( > 20 mins) or after a reboot, the first request takes quite some time to respond. Maybe 45 seconds. After that initial lagged request it acts as expected, replying with web-pages very quickly.

To try and fix the problem I have so far set the directive "HostnameLookups Off" in /usr/local/zend/apache2/conf/httpd.conf. It hasn't helped.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue, you have to add the ipv6 version also or it takes forever...

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     yoursite.local
::1           yoursite.local
```

The ::1 line will fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, but only when using Safari. I don't understand the logic behind it, but Zend Server requests are sent as I would expect running Firefox. Try it out and let me know, if it works, then it's not a problem with Zend Server.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to matter which browser I use. The first response is slow, then subsequent responses are snappy.

Comment: its not a Zend issue, see my answer below